# mod_rewrite to eliminate .html or .php

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

This might have been discussed over and over again here, but never got to make it work. Currently I am running my website on my local host (wamp) I need to eliminate the .html extension I have got more than couple of files which needs REWRITE.

alltourplaces.php
tourplaces.php
etc.

The link I provide for alltourplaces.php is Resorts.html or City-Hotels.html or Liveaboards.html etc.

The link for tourplaces.php is Coco-Palm.html or Trades-Hotel.html or Princess-Haleema.html etc.

I had tried without using the .html as well but it gives the error.

Below is the .htaccess code I had used

```
options -indexes
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^1zevens/(.*)\.html$ /1zevens/alltourplaces.php?tptName=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^1zevens/(.*)\.html$ /1zevens/tourplaces.php?tpsName=$1 [L]
```

Where am I going wrong here?

Comment: Did you try the lazy version: `^1zevens/(.?).html$`?

Comment: Correction (forgot to escape the dot): `^1zevens/(.?)\.html$`

Comment: just tried it... it still doe show the .html and yet it shows the ERROR page as well. i don't want to have the .html on the address bar

Comment: Please give full exmples of the intended user URL and target internal URL, so we understand the mapping you want to achieve.

Comment: this is the href am using <a class="plces" href="Coco-Palm.html" title="View Details of Coco-Palm">Coco-Palm</a> this is used in alltourplaces.php to find it on tourplaces.php, the website is http://www.zevensmaldives.com

Comment: Both rules have the same match-expression, so only the first one is ever executed. You haven't explained what the problem is with your current code. Does it not work? Does it work partially? Do you want to change it to remove the `.html` part?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RewriteRule ^/?1zevens/(.*?)(\.html)?$ /1zevens/alltourplaces.php?tptName=$1 [L]
```

does it work now? Also consider **enabling logging** using `RewriteLog`, and check the log file for what the rules do.

Comment: isn't this the same as what i have already tried in my question

Comment: No. It has an extra slash, which you might be missing. But without you giving full "is" and "should" URLs, it is hard to help you. It is okay to use `http://www.example.com/1zevens/example.html` and not use your real domain name.

Comment: with the current code in .htacess it is still working fine.. i need the .html to be removed and yet it to work perfectly, as i mentioned before this is something i am using in localhost but the uploaded site is there as well. jst need to remove the .html part of it :/

Comment: Sorry, apparenty I still do not understand *what* you want to achieve. Please give full examples, of what you currently have and what you want to achieve.

Comment: ok this is how the current URL is like http://localhost/1zevens/Resorts-Paradise_Island_Resort_and_Spa.html , but i want it to be without the extension at the very end eg:http://localhost/1zevens/Resorts-Paradise_Island_Resort_and_Spa , i tried but it wouldn't work for me.

Comment: Try the latest edit of my reply. The `.html` should be optional now; if it is still present it will however be ignored.